# how to calculate the overlap area - postgis, postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, overlap, area

how to calculate the overlap area?

```
select ST_Area(ST_Overlaps(geometrya, geometryb)::geometry) from table_name;
```

Error Message cannot cast type boolean to geometry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ST_OVERLAPS`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Overlaps.html) returns a boolean indicating if the geometries do or not overlap each other. To get the geometry of the intersection you can use [`ST_INTERSECTION`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html)

```
select ST_Area(ST_INTERSECTION(geometrya, geometryb)) from table_name
 WHERE ST_Overlaps(geometrya, geometryb);
```

Comment: but intersection is diff from overlap?

Comment: @user nyes... overlap is false if a geometry contains the other one. Other than that, the common area is the intersection. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks! But looks like i hit a snag, my geometry coordinates are in the form of (x,y,0) and ST_area is giving non-zero values Example - "2.6030917519796e-05".

Comment: Have a look at [ST_SnapToGrid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) to avoid these tiny overlaps/disjoints